# ? LIKE (column || '%')

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, prefix

Can I have a condition of something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? LIKE (column || '%')
```

Where the `?` is a string parameter value. For example, these **parameter value `?`** should return true when column is equal to `/admin/products`

```
/admin/products/1
/admin/products/new
/admin/products/1/edit
```

Is this possible?

**Update:** Added test case.

Basically, the where clause would render like this:

```
1.  ? LIKE (column || '%')
2.  '/admin/products/1' like ('/admin/products' || %)
3.  '/admin/products/1' like ('/admin/products%')
```

But it always return false for me.

These queries works fine though:

```
column = '/admin/products' --returns true
column = '/admin/products/1' --returns false
column LIKE '/admin/prod%' --returns true
```

The problem arises when I put the parameter `?` before the `LIKE` clause. Is it not allowed?
If it's not, are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: AFAIK Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters.

Comment: This sounds like a front end/ implementation issue, not a database issue.

Comment: @Scotch We were actually implementing a user role on our system. We put URL of base pages on the database and validate it in our base controller of the administration site so that we wouldn't have any redundant codes.

Comment: In SQL `+` is the operator to add numbers, it's not for character concatenation (the operator to concatenate strings is `||`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Noted, fixed the question regarding SQL string concatenation symbol.

Comment: It should work fine, but maybe you'll need to use quotes explicitly: '?' LIKE column || '%'

Comment: @Multisync Not working though. The query renders like this `'admin/products/1/edit' like ('admin/products' || '%')`.

Comment: Can you show a complete test case? This looks fine as written.

Comment: @CraigRinger Added test case on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? LIKE (col || '%');
```

can be rewritten as (Postgres and MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = left(?, length(col));
```

As commented, the first form should work as well. It can be tricky, though, because **characters with special meaning** for [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) (at least `_%\`) *in the column* would have to be escaped. If you want it to work with both MySQL and Postgres, you'll have to observe special characters in both implementations. So the 2nd form is **much less error-prone** on principal.

#### Performance

Neither of these queries can use an index on `col`, both are not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). The problem can be re-assessed as finding all possible prefixes to the given search pattern `?`, which can be optimized in a similar fashion like in this related answer (for Postgres) on dba.SE:

- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43444/3684)

Comment: Thank you very much! It also works on MySQL. You save me a day of work.

Comment: It still doesn't explain *why* the original issue arose, but it'll sure do the job.

Comment: The first form should work as well. It can be tricky, though, because special characters like `_%\\` *in the column* would have to be escaped. So the 2nd form is much less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? LIKE (column || '%')
```

by

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT(column, '%')
```

works for me.

Maybe || is used as logical or-operation instead of concatenation.

Comment: Thanks! Will it work on postgre too? Our production database is actualy on postgre, and our dev environment is on MySQL.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona: I would strongly suggest to use the same RDBMS for dev & production, or you'll keep running into "surprising" problems. There is also a [`concat()` function in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) but `||` is the standard-SQL concatenation operator. And [the name is not "postgre"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter They actually state that *All other names are incorrect, especially Postgre* in their documentation, lol, sorry. My colleagues was also using PostgreSQL but I need a better IDE for my database (on-table editing and stuff) which I can't find for PostgreSQL (am using MySQL Workbench). But I personally think dolphins and elephants are the same ;)

Comment: @John PostgreSQL since 9.1 also has a `concat` function, working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07da7/1

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
PREPARE withparam(text) AS SELECT $1 LIKE ('/admin/products' || '%');

EXECUTE withparam('/admin/products/1');
```

returns true.

Your test case doesn't appear to accurately reflect the actual issue at hand.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. :p Already fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona I'm still convinced your real issue is elsewhere and the testcase doesn't really reflect what you're doing. It makes no sense that `select '/admin/products/1' like ('/admin/products%')` could return false for you.

Comment: I actually checked the generated SQL query by debugging and it is `'/admin/products/1' like (url || '%')` but it really returns false. I think the problem is on the implementation of the `like` condition not allowing the table name after it. But running your query on MySQL returns true. Thanks for helping though! I really appreciate it!