# Progressive search for longest prefix

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching, prefix

I have a table with phone number prefix columns like:

```
prefix
------
9379
355422
35566
...
```

Given a phone number I want to drop its digits starting from the right until It finds the first match on the prefix column. ie:

```
937973418459
93797341845
9379734184
937973418
93797341
9379734
937973
93797
9379   <-- match found
```

Note that I need to do this for a list of phone numbers so bulk operation is important as opposed to individual query which is slow. I tried using postgres' full-text search using:

```
tsquery('937973418459|93797341845|9379734184|937973418|93797341|9379734|937973|93797|9379')
```

and it works but its slow when running against say 10k phone numbers. It there a more efficient way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the ***longest prefix***:

For a *single* given number:

```
SELECT *
FROM   prefix_tbl
WHERE  937973418459 LIKE prefix || '%'
ORDER  BY prefix DESC
LIMIT  1
```

For a whole table of given numbers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.nr )
       p.*
FROM   prefix_tbl p
JOIN   tel_nr t ON t.nr LIKE p.prefix || '%'
ORDER  BY t.nr, prefix DESC;
```

Related:

- [? LIKE (column || '%')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989488/like-column/26990031#26990031)

For **performance optimization** consider this closely related, extensive answer on dba.SE:

- [Algorithm for finding the longest prefix](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43444/3684)

And this:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Works like charm, and the links are superb! ;)